# jQuery GET inject code into div and refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the source code from a local file using jQuery GET and injecting the code into a `div`.

My problem is that this code is not refreshing.

**jQuery**

```
jQuery.get("some_local_file_url_here", function( the_page_source ) {

    jQuery("#target_div").html(the_page_source);

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="target_div"> the_page_source goes here </div>
```

How can I get it to work as it I did a reload to the page?

Comment: "this code is not refreshing"—can you pin point where the error is originating from? Check your console log—what does it say? Many things could have gone wrong: jQuery not being loaded properly, the URL is incorrect, the target div is generated dynamically after runtime... and etc. Also useful to check the browser's network/resources tab to see if the URL is loaded properly and returning a 200 status code.

Comment: What do u mean by `this code is not refreshing`??!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    jQuery.get("some_local_file_url_here", function( the_page_source ) {

        jQuery("#target_div").html(the_page_source);

    });
}, 3000);
```

The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds).

TIPS:

**3000** = every 3 seconds

**1000** = 1 second

You can change it.

read more: [Window setInterval() Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

Comment: setInterval with no interval set executes every how many microseconds?

Comment: How does wrapping the code in a setInterval solve the problem? It's always best to explain how code helps so that others can learn, rather than copy-pasting solutions which they don't understand.